# React-Redux how to save state

Tags: redux, react-redux, state

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to save the state in my app. I have a component where a user adds a 'NAME' and a 'WEIGHT'. When the user clicks the submit button, it redirects them to the Home Page and the newly added name is displayed (the weight will be displayed elsewhere).
What I'm having trouble with is when I go back and add another 'NAME' and 'WEIGHT', the previous name disappears and is replaced with the new one. What I would like to happen is have the previous 'NAME' stay on the Home Page when I add a new one.

Here is my AddPage component:

```
const AddPage = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [weight, setWeight] = useState(0);
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <div>
            <Header title="Add Page" />
            <div className={classes.addPage}>
                <div className={classes.addMovementDiv}>
                    <TextField 
                        className={classes.movementName} 
                        key="name" 
                        label="Enter Movement Name" 
                        InputProps= {{className: "textBoxColor"}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={event => {
                            const { value } = event.target;
                            setName(value);
                        }}
                         
                        
                         />    
                    <TextField 
                        className={classes.movementWeight} 
                        key="weight" 
                        label="Enter Movement Weight" 
                        type="number" 
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={event => {
                            const { value } = event.target;
                            setWeight(value);
                        }}
                        
                        InputProps= {{endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">lb</InputAdornment>, className: "textBoxColor"}} />
                    <Button 
                        className={classes.addButton}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onClick={() => dispatch(addMovement(name, weight))}
                        >
                        <AddCircleIcon />
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.move.name,
        weight: state.move.weight,   
    }   
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return({
        addMovement: (name, weight) => dispatch(addMovement(name, weight)),
    })
};

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(AddPage);
```

Here is my HomePage component:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const name  = useSelector(state => state.move.name);

    const displayMovementButtons = () => {
        if (name) {
            return (
                <Button 
                    className={classes.movementButtons}
                    onClick={() => history.push('/movement/:id')}
                >   
                <div className={classes.movementName} >{name}</div>
                </Button>
            )
        } 

        return <div className={classes.noMovementsMessage} >Click add button to begin</div>
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.homePageContent} >
            <Header title={"Home Page" }/>
            <div>{displayMovementButtons()}</div>
            <div className={classes.fabDiv}>
                <Fab 
                    className={classes.fab}
                    onClick={() => history.push(`/add`)}>  
                    <AddIcon />      
                </Fab>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.move.name,  
    }   
};

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(HomePage);
```

Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = []

const addMovementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MOVEMENT: 
            return [ ...state, {name: action.name, weight: action.weight} ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default addMovementReducer;
```

Here is where my store is set up:

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you're misusing redux state by using it along side with hooks. it's an either or situation

may I see your store and reducer ?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've update the question to include my reducer and store.